# How to Select first 30 chars in a sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

SELECT  First 20 Chars of(ColName) from DB

Is this possible?

Comment: Be aware that if you have a large result set, this may get slow.  If this is for display, you may be better returning the whole string (providing it's not too large), and splitting down only those records you need to show.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT left(ColName,20) AS First20 /*(Or 30 if we are looking at the title)*/
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SUBSTRING(ColName, 1, 30)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), ColName) from DB
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that colname is VARCHAR, all the above will pad shorter strings to 20 characters.

If this is not what you want, then:

SELECT RTRIM(LEFT(colname, 20)) FROM DB

Comment: None of these will pad the string with spaces that it did not originally contain. There is no need for `RTRIM`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use one of the built in [**string functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx).  There are many variants so its best to see which one suits your situation best.

Enjoy!